# MSSQL and PHP echos repeating rows for same information

Tags: php, sql-server

I am sorry about the title as I am not sure whether my problem is in the PHP or the MSSQL query. I am pretty sure it is php.

I am repairing a PHP page that accesses two different MSSQL tables. the page worked fine until we had a system-wide change that created new department ID's and hence some new department names.

I have this almost completely fixed now except one minor thing. When you click List all departments, it Lists all the departments and each link has the correct individuals under them.

The problem is it lists a link for EACH individual in that department name for example if there are 10 people in the Business department we have ten links to Business and all have the same information under them.

I want to make it so there is only 1 link for each department. the two tables are directory (columns involved are Displayname and Department) and departments (columns involved are name and id)

Can someone please tell me where I need to change this so it only prints one link to each department? Is the problem with my SQL query or the PHP?

here is the code

```
function listDepts() {

$query = "SELECT directory.Lastname, directory.Firstname, directory.email, 
directory.phone, directory.Office, directory.Department, departments.id, 
 departments.name FROM directory FULL JOIN departments ON 
directory.Department=departments.id  ORDER BY name";

$result = mssql_query($query);

echo "<h3>Please select a department:</h3>\n";
echo "<ul>\n";

for ($i=0; $i<mssql_num_rows($result); ) {
    $info = mssql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo "<li><a href=\"dept.php?dept=$info[id]\">$info[name]</a></li>\n";
}

echo "</ul>\n\n";

}
```

Other query

```
function displayResults($query) {

$result = mssql_query($query);

if (mssql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    for ($i=0; $i<mssql_num_rows($result); $i++) {
        $info = mssql_fetch_assoc($result);

        if ($info[dept_name] != $last_dept) {
            if ($i > 0) {
                echo "</table>\n\n";
            }

            echo "<h3><a href=\"$info[dept_url]\">$info[dept_name]</a></h3>\n\n";
            echo "<table id=\"directory_table\">\n";
            echo "<tr>\n";
            echo "<th>Name</th>\n";
            echo "<th>E-mail</th>\n";
            echo "<th>Phone</th>\n";
            echo "<th>Office</th>\n";
            echo "<th>Title</th>\n";
            echo "</tr>\n";
        }


        if (!$info[dept_name] && $i==0) {
            echo "<table id=\"directory_table\">\n";
            echo "<tr>\n";
            echo "<th>Name</th>\n";
            echo "<th>E-mail</th>\n";
            echo "<th>Phone</th>\n";
            echo "<th>Office</th>\n";
            echo "<th>Title</th>\n";
            echo "</tr>\n";
        }

        if ($i % 2 == 0) {
            echo "<tr class=\"even\">\n";
        } else {
            echo "<tr class=\"odd\">\n";
        }

        echo "<td>";
        echo ($info[Firstname]) ? "$info[Firstname]" . " " . "$info[Lastname]" : "&nbsp;";
        echo "</td>\n";

        echo "<td>";
        echo ($info[email]) ? "<a href=\"mailto:$info[email]\">$info[email]</a>" : "&nbsp;";
        echo "</td>\n";

        echo "<td>";
        echo ($info[phone]) ? "$info[phone]" : "&nbsp;";
        echo "</td>\n";

        echo "<td>";
        echo ($info[office]) ? "$info[office]" : "&nbsp;";
        echo "</td>\n";

        echo "<td>";
        echo ($info[title]) ? "$info[title]" : "&nbsp;";
        echo "</td>\n";

        $last_dept = $info[dept_name];
    }

    echo "</table>\n\n";

} else {
    echo "<p>No results found.</p>\n\n";
}

}
```

Comment: increment $i in for loop first thing I see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only using these two fields:

```
echo "<li><a href=\"dept.php?dept=$info[id]\">$info[name]</a></li>\n";
```

Why not just make your select query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    name 
FROM 
    departments 
ORDER BY 
    name
```

You're not using anything from the `directory` table, so you don't need to take anything from it.

If you've got multiple departments, try:

```
echo "<li><a href=\"dept.php?dept=$info[name]\">$info[name]</a></li>\n";
```

And then updating your department code to search for employees in the department with that name.

Department code:

```
$theSQL = "SELECT * FROM directory WHERE department IN (SELECT id FROM departments WHERE name='$department') ORDER BY Lastname");
```

Comment: we also need to show the office location, phone, and email for each person. the name is actually the department name. the echo provides the hyperlink information to the list of names for that department the names of the people in the department as well as contact information come from the directory table.

Comment: The code in your question doesn't do anything with location, phone or email.

Comment: hmm.. ok I will check that out I have been playing around with the code that was already there assuming that because ti worked before that teh previous author had not made any mistakes.

Comment: If all you want to do is list the name and a hyperlink for each department, the above SQL should do fine. I hope.

Comment: Andrewsi thank you that worked to a point except now that I have that the people in a department that have a different department code are listed under a separate link by the same displayname

Comment: `function listDepts() {

 $query = "SELECT  id, name FROM     departments ORDER BY     name";
 $result = mssql_query($query);

 echo "<h3>Please select a department:</h3>\n";
 echo "<ul>\n";

 for ($i=0; $i<mssql_num_rows($result); $i++) {
  $info = mssql_fetch_assoc($result);
  echo "<li><a href=\"dept.php?dept=$info[id]\">$info[name]</a></li>\n";
 }

 echo "</ul>\n\n";

}
`  this is what I have right now

Comment: I am thinking I need a join somewhere, probably by department name

Comment: I don't think that will help. If you've got two Accounting departments with IDs of 1 and 2, how does your code to display employees work? Can it take multiple IDs? Or does it just display one?

Comment: The original way I had it displayed multiple id's under one department name but it printed multiple links to the department name

Comment: You can also change the code so that you're passing the name of the department as the parameter, rather than the ID - that would pick up both Accounting departments.

Comment: and where would I change that at? Sorry for asking but I have tried changing so many thing I am getting myself confused

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to pass the department name; I can't tell you how to update the code that lists the employees without seeing the code.

Comment: Ok thanks for doing that, I had tried that and ran into the problem that it still shows multiple links but then it doesn't display any information under the links. By the way that is the entire sql query for that particular employee search type

Comment: I've changed the query. It will now list distinct department names. The links it generates won't work until you update the code - the code is expecting a department ID and you're now passing it a department name.

Comment: Ok we are much closer it is now displaying distinct department names but when clicking the link it does not display names. I will add the other code on the page to my original question maybe that will tell us where the problem is.

Comment: You'll need to add the part that generates the SQL that's used in `displayResults`

Comment: Ok again I feel dumb but how?  I thought I knew SQL but this is kicking my rear big time.

Comment: `displayResults` is passed in a variable called `$query`. You'll need to add the part of the code that sets that up.

Comment: that is part of my problem this is part of the page that the previous person had done and I have not been able to figure out where they defined the $query.

Comment: All you need to do is find where they're calling displayResult, and work backwards from there. If you're using unix, then `grep -r -i displayresult` will show you where it's being called from.

Comment: the other page linked to this has the  following code         `$department = $_GET['dept'];

// This will evaluate to TRUE so the text will be printed.
if (isset($department)) {



// Send a select query to MSSQL

$query = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM directory WHERE Department = '$department' ORDER BY Lastname");`
But for the life of me I can not figure out where the $_GET['dept'] came from because neither table has that column.  I have been thinking the problem lies there.

Comment: I've added a couple more lines to my answer, to replace that second `mssql_query`. $_GET['dept'] is one of the variables that PHP sets, and says to use the value of `dept` passed in as part of the URL.

Comment: Andrew I could kiss you! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop at the end of each iteration $i needs to be evaluated.
It should be like

```
for ($i=0; $i<mssql_num_rows($result); $i++)
```

Another way (generally) of looping is

```
$query = mssql_query('your_query');
while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($query)){
  echo "<li><a href=\"dept.php?dept=$row['id']\">$row['name']</a></li>\n";
}
```